# Invalid advertisement payload when using BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataSection in Advertisement

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-universal, beacon

I am a BLE newbie. I am using my Raspberry Pi 3, running Windows 10 Iot Core, to send some advertisement packets.

When sending only the Manufacturer Data, it works perfectly fine. But when I try to send data in Data Section, it gives me the following error.

> The data is invalid. Invalid advertisement payload detected

Here is the code

Using only Manufacturer Data

```
private void StartPublish()
    {
        string data = "SHASHWAT";
        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter();
        writer.WriteInt32(data.Length);
        writer.WriteString(data);
        var adv = new BluetoothLEAdvertisement();

        var manufacturerData = new BluetoothLEManufacturerData(
          0x0006, writer.DetachBuffer());

        adv.ManufacturerData.Add(manufacturerData);

        var publisher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher(adv);

        publisher.Start();
    }
```

Using Data Section along with Manufacturer Data

```
private void StartPublishWithDataSection()
    {
        string data = "SHASHWAT";
        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter();
        writer.WriteInt32(data.Length);
        writer.WriteString(data);
        var adv = new BluetoothLEAdvertisement();

        var manufacturerData = new BluetoothLEManufacturerData(
          0x0006, writer.DetachBuffer());

        adv.ManufacturerData.Add(manufacturerData);

        DataWriter writer2 = new DataWriter();
        writer2.WriteString("Hello Shashwat");
        var dataSection = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataSection();
        dataSection.Data = writer2.DetachBuffer();
        adv.DataSections.Add(dataSection);

        var publisher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher(adv);

        publisher.Start();
    }
```

This throws invalid data exception.

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of this exception is advertisement payload length exceeds the limitation(official state this value is ~20 bytes). You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/ble-beacon#publishing-advertisements).

Based on my tests, the maximum length of the advertisement payload is 25 bytes including `BluetoothLEManufacturerData` and `BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataSection`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I dont think length is the issue. I checked this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementpublisher), it mentions advertisement types that are system-reserved. I set a different type than these, and it worked.

Comment: The type was 0x66, and i kept the data same. "Shashwat" in manufacturer data and "Hello Shashwat" for 0x66 type data in data section.

Comment: Have you tried to send more data? Is it still working?

Comment: No, i did not try with more data.